# Join json data dynamically in client side to use in kendogrid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am getting data from 2 different data sources. Can I join the second data set with the original data and use in kendo grid.

sample scenario http://jsfiddle.net/Jomet/k6420L5L/

```
            //Join data in Client script
        var myJson = {"employees":[
            {"Id": 1 ,"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
            {"Id": 2 ,"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
            {"Id": 3 ,"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
        ]};

        var myJson2 = {"employees":[
            {"Id": 1 , "location":"Toronto"},
            {"Id": 2 , "location":"Toronto"},
            {"Id": 3 , "location":"Vaughan"}
        ]};


        for (var i = 0; i < myJson2.employees.length; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j < myJson.employees.length; j++) {
            if (myJson2.employees[i].Id == myJson.employees[j].Id) {
              myJson.employees[j]["location"] = myJson2.employees[i]["location"];
            }
          }
        }

        var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: myJson.employees,
            pageSize: 10
        });

        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource:  ds    
        });
```

In short Can I join data in client script? which is the best way.

UPDATE: Myself found a solution by looping through array and updated the fiddle. Please suggest if it can be done in a better way ..

Comment: array1.concat(array2). see the example 
https://jsfiddle.net/k8ym12n4/2/

Comment: it is merged now, array with 6 rows, not joined